# Orbeon using xxf:lang() as condition

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am trying to use XForms xxf:lang() function in Orbeon form to conditionaly hide a field.

Here is code in Visibility parameter of field:

```
xxf:lang() = 'en'
```

Here is an example:
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/9c1a13452fdd728b7c5545d3c7a981bceb93f677

After hitting 'Test' button form is not loaded. What is wrong with tjhat form? How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that XPath expression, instead of `xxf:lang()`, use `fr:lang()` ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-form-runner#fr-lang)), and it will do exactly what you expected.